# Can I keep the Git repository name in a CircleCI workspace?

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

My project configures its artifact name using the name of the project root directory. Is it possible to configure CircleCI 2.0 to checkout the Git repository to a directory with the same name (i.e., the default behaviour of `git clone`)?

(Cross posted to [the CircleCI support channel](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/can-i-keep-the-git-repository-name-in-a-circleci-workspace/20142)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can do so either by telling the `checkout` command the name of the direction: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#checkout

Or by setting a custom `working_directory`: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#job_name

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: Just as a side-note, we prefer posts not to be signed here - we like Q&A material to be as succinct as possible. Thanks!

Comment: (Hmm, that said, it is useful for folks to know you're posting on behalf of an organisation - I will ask a question on Meta tomorrow about it).

Comment: Will be happy to do so - [the discussion is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363528/should-editors-excise-signatures-in-answers-even-if-they-contain-useful-organisa), but too early to say what the consensus will be. It tends to twist and turn over a few days `:0)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer! I solved my use-case by setting the project name to $CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME within the build.